# Sending TLS/SSL secured POST requests from node.js to IIS

Tags: node.js, ssl, iis, https, request

I have a node.js webapp running on IIS 8.5 (published using [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)) on my Windows Server 2012 and I have configured it to use [this](https://www.mrdomain.com/products/ssl/dondominio-domain-ssl/) certificate I just bought. So I added the certificate to the server:

[image]

And configured my website to use https and the certificate I have just configured:

[image]

Now I can access my website like https://example.com

Ok, I have node.js clients running on some computers outside my network and posting some data to the server from time to time. I want to secure that connection now that I have a SSL certificate.

My goal would be to do the HTTPS POST from client and only the clients using a valid certificate would be allowed to upload data to my https://example.com/upload url.

So first, I forced ISS to ask for a certificate on my website. In SSL configuration I checked the "Required" option:[image]

Next thing to do is to upload data from my node.js using https and my cert. The problem is that my node.js https POST request is getting the IIS's permission denied website as a response.

My node.js request code is:

```
var config = require('./config');
var request     = require('request');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');  

var certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tls/certificate.crt');
var keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tls/certificate.key');
var caFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tls/certificate.ca.crt');
var pfxFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tls/certificate.pfx');



var credentials ={
    "email":config.EMAIL,
    "password":config.PASSWORD
}

request.post({
    uri: config.LOGIN_URL, //https://example.com/upload
    headers: { 
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
    },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    agentOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
        // Or use `pfx` property replacing `cert` and `key` when using private key, certificate and CA certs in PFX or PKCS12 format:
        // pfx: fs.readFileSync(pfxFilePath),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(caFile),
        securityOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3'
    }
}, function(err, res, body){
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log('OK!');
        } else  { 
            console.log("Error: ",err);    
        }
});
```

What I am missing in my architecture so that IIS allows my HTTPS POST requests validating the certificate I send from client?

EDIT: I am testing now ussing in node.js client the same pfx file I have added in the server (IIS). My agentOpntions now are:

```
 agentOptions: {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync(pfxFile),
            passphrase: 'MyPfxPassPhrase',
            securityOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3'
        }
```

Same result :(

EDIT2: I use free cloudflare service as DNS and a little extra security (DDos protection, etc). I don't know if this can cause the issue...

EDIT3: I read on Internet that maybe I had to create a One-to-one mapping with a windows user so I followed [this](http://itq.nl/testing-with-client-certificate-authentication-in-a-development-environment-on-iis-8-5/) guide to configure it. Same result: 403- Permission denied.

EDIT 4: I activated the SSL Error tracking and now i can see the exact error code is: `HTTP 403.16 Forbidden: Client Certificate Untrusted or Invalid.` Exactly, the log is:

```
<failedRequest url="https://example.com:443/"
               siteId="6"
               appPoolId="example"
               processId="3544"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0D00-0080000000F7}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="403.16"
               triggerStatusCode="403.16"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
</failedRequest>
```

I don't know if maybe I need to add COMODO RSA CA to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store, to the Intermediate Certificate Authority (CA) or to the External Root Certification Authorities...
My certificate has the folowing certification path:

[image]

EDIT5: I used wireshark to capture the TLS negotiation. This is the result, I am not able to draw any conclusion with it:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you show the code for the server?

Comment: Also, the error log you posted seems to be for a GET request..

Comment: Just open up Wireshark and try to see how the TLS negotiation went.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari You are right. That error is a GET request because I am testing the issue on the browser going to the website https://www.example.com using the browser with the cert configured in it. I am getting the same error  (permission denied) when I should see the website because I am accredited by the cert. I think it is a good way to test it.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari about the code of the server, it is just a website served in node.js. The permission denied error is sent by IIS, a SW layer before the website is served so I guess it is not the websites fault, but ISS'

Comment: @arboreal84 I installed wireshark and captured the TLS negotiation. I edited the OP with the capture of the packets. I am not able to see any error there, everything seems to be correct?